# how to view a object without name object in react native?

Tags: react-native

Object {
  "0": 200,
  "result": Array [
    Object {
      "created_at": "1572602716",
      "description": "i am description ",
      "id": "1",
      "title": "gulsan",
      "updated_at": "1572602716",
      "user_id": "27",
    },
    Object {
      "created_at": "1572603684",
      "description": "i am description ",
      "id": "2",
      "title": "kunal",
      "updated_at": "1572603684",
      "user_id": "27",
    },
    Object {
      "created_at": "1572603975",
      "description": "i am description ",
      "id": "3",
      "title": "nil",
      "updated_at": "1572603975",
      "user_id": "27",
    },
    Object {
      "created_at": "1572854783",
      "description": "i am description ",
      "id": "7",
      "title": "nilakash",
      "updated_at": "1572854783",
      "user_id": "27",
    },
    Object {
      "created_at": "1573114400",
      "description": "123",
      "id": "8",
      "title": "Tapan@gmail.com",
      "updated_at": "1573114400",
      "user_id": "27",
    },
    Object {
      "created_at": "1573114522",
      "description": "Test",
      "id": "9",
      "title": "Test",
      "updated_at": "1573114522",
      "user_id": "27",
    },
    Object {
      "created_at": "1573114525",
      "description": "Test",
      "id": "10",
      "title": "Test",
      "updated_at": "1573114525",
      "user_id": "27",
    },
  ],
}

how to view it component

const obj = state.find((p) => p.title === "nil");
  console.log(obj)

output

Object {
  "created_at": "1572603975",
  "description": "i am description ",
  "id": "3",
  "title": "nil",
  "updated_at": "1572603975",
  "user_id": "27",
}
i want show it component

Comment: this object have no name

Comment: Can you add your component code to the question?

Comment: yes  i want to view component

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the below snippet, you can view the object using this way.

```js
 var obj = "{\"0\": 200,\"result\": [{\"created_at\": \"1572602716\",\"description\": \"i am description \",\"id\": \"1\",\"title\": \"gulsan\",\"updated_at\": \"1572602716\",\"user_id\": \"27\"}, {\"created_at\": \"1572603684\",\"description\": \"i am description \",\"id\": \"2\",\"title\": \"kunal\",\"updated_at\": \"1572603684\",\"user_id\": \"27\"}, {\"created_at\": \"1572603975\",\"description\": \"i am description \",\"id\": \"3\",\"title\": \"nil\",\"updated_at\": \"1572603975\",\"user_id\": \"27\"}, {\"created_at\": \"1572854783\",\"description\": \"i am description \",\"id\": \"7\",\"title\": \"nilakash\",\"updated_at\": \"1572854783\",\"user_id\": \"27\"}, {\"created_at\": \"1573114400\",\"description\": \"123\",\"id\": \"8\",\"title\": \"Tapan@gmail.com\",\"updated_at\": \"1573114400\",\"user_id\": \"27\"}, {\"created_at\": \"1573114522\",\"description\": \"Test\",\"id\": \"9\",\"title\": \"Test\",\"updated_at\": \"1573114522\",\"user_id\": \"27\"}, {\"created_at\": \"1573114525\",\"description\": \"Test\",\"id\": \"10\",\"title\": \"Test\",\"updated_at\": \"1573114525\",\"user_id\": \"27\"}]}";
 
 var jsonObj = JSON.parse(obj);
 console.log(jsonObj.result[0]);
```